# Plot Impulse Response Function (new)

Tags: r, plot

I'm using the [vars package](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/vars/docs/print.varirf) to visualize impulse responses. Example:

```
library(vars)
Canada <- Canada * 1000
var <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "both")
plot(irf(var, impulse = "rw", response = "U", boot = T, cumulative = FALSE,     n.ahead = 20))
```

However, the plot function is currently not perfectly suited to my needs and I prefer to make my own plot with the data. Now, how can I visualize the data in

```
irf(var, impulse = "rw", response = "U", boot = T, cumulative = FALSE,     n.ahead = 20)
```

? If possible, I would also prefer to draw a 95% band (filled area between the upper and lower 95% level) rather than an upper and lower line.

Comment: It's hard to know what you want, when you don't explain why you find the base plot.irf to be lacking (I understand you completely though - I made my own plots for impulse response functions i ggplot2, but what I found lacking might not the be same as what you find lacking)

Comment: This problem has also bothered me for a while.  I wrote a function to extract the relevant vectors from the `irf` function in the `vars` package to a format that is ggplot friendly.  Example and links to code [here](https://mentalbreaks.rbind.io/posts/impulse-reponse-plots-with-vars-and-ggplot2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have your `irf` object in `data` you can first collect the data you need in a `data.frame`, and then use this object to plot in `ggplot2`

This step can no doubt be done much simpler and cleaner, but this is what I have:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

variables <- data$irf %>% names

ir <- lapply(1:length(variables), function(e){
    data_to_plot <- data.frame(data %>% `$`(irf) %>% `[[`(variables[e])) %>%
      mutate("t" = 1:NROW(.)) %>%
      gather(.,Variable, Value, -t)

    upper_ci <- data.frame(data %>% `$`(Upper) %>% `[[`(variables[e])) %>%
      mutate("t" = 1:NROW(.)) %>%
      gather(.,Variable, Upper, -t)

    lower_ci <- data.frame(data %>% `$`(Lower) %>% `[[`(variables[e]) ) %>%
      mutate("t" = 1:NROW(.)) %>%
      gather(.,Variable, Lower, -t)

    res <- inner_join(data_to_plot, upper_ci, c("t","Variable")) %>%
           inner_join(.,lower_ci, c("t","Variable")) %>%
           mutate(impulse = paste("Shock to", variables[e])) 
}) %>% rbind_all
```

This yields a `data.frame` called `ir` with the following setup:

```
       t Variable     Value     Upper     Lower       impulse
   (int)    (chr)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)         (chr)
1      1     Var2 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 Shock to Var2
2      2     Var2 0.7954066 0.7995073 0.7914643 Shock to Var2
3      3     Var2 0.6089447 0.6151634 0.6028292 Shock to Var2
4      4     Var2 0.4588737 0.4649281 0.4533494 Shock to Var2
5      5     Var2 0.2273798 0.2344760 0.2220514 Shock to Var2
6      6     Var2 0.1762154 0.1831608 0.1691510 Shock to Var2
7      7     Var2 0.1349820 0.1454106 0.1278052 Shock to Var2
8      8     Var2 0.1203771 0.1310155 0.1119077 Shock to Var2
9      9     Var2 0.1150205 0.1255296 0.1050281 Shock to Var2
10    10     Var2 0.1121840 0.1263839 0.1009568 Shock to Var2
..   ...      ...       ...       ...       ...           ...
```

The key point is you want the characters for factors, `variable` and `impulse` for plotting in `ggplot2`. `Lower` and `Upper` are the bands defined by the `irf` function. You can specify them to be whatever level of CI you want I believe.

Using `ggplot2` you first plot the actual impulse (called `Value` here) and then add dashed lines for the two confidence bands:

```
ggplot(ir, aes(x = t, y = Value, colour = Variable))  +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = t, y = Upper, colour = Variable), linetype = 2, size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = t, y = Lower, colour = Variable), linetype = 2, size = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("steelblue", "firebrick2", "forestgreen")) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,20), breaks = 1:20) +
  facet_wrap(~impulse, ncol = 1) +
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        text = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

Yielding something like:

[image: Impulse Response Function]

Comment: Somehow, the confidence intervals make no sense?

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong. Is it the plotting of CI that is wrong, or do you mean the CI data is wrong?

Comment: It would be better ti visualize only one variable and then the CI bands (rather as a fileld area, not as two lines). In the current graphs, the dashed lines are almost invisible. But I get an idea of how it can be done w/o ggplot..

Comment: You can choose another `geom` if you feel like it. `geom_area` is the one you are looking for, but you might have to rescale the data.